# Throw me away. Who am I?

Tags: riddle, word

> When you need me, you throw me away.
>   But when you’re done with me, you bring me back.

***What am I?***

---

<sub>*This is not one of my riddles. If anyone knows who created this riddle, 
I would be delighted to hear it!*</sub>

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It could be

> an anchor

because

> an anchor's purpose is to hold a ship in place. To do that, it has to be dropped. When the ship is leaving, the anchor is pulled back up.

Answer (score 14):

Is it a

> Fishing Net

because

> when you need to use it you throw it in the water, and when caught enough fishes you pull it back.

Answer (score 7):

You are a;

> Dart

When you need me, you throw me away.

> You throw it to hit the target

But when you’re done with me, you bring me back.

> When it is end of your turn, you pull your dart back from the target

Answer (score 4):

> You're a lifebuoy.

When you need me, you throw me away.

> To someone who is drowning.

But when you’re done with me, you bring me back.

> Together with saved person.

Answer (score 4):

I wonder why noone had my first idea - it is a

> spear

because

> you throw it when you need it for hunt, and bring it back home when you're done.

Answer (score 3):

While the popular answer to this well-known riddle is

> an anchor on a ship.

I would like to offer an alternative that works just as well. I think the subject of this riddle is

> a kite.
> When you want to play with a kite, you will throw it away from you to get it flying. When you are done playing, you reel it back in.

Answer (score 1):

> An anchor of a ship.

Because

> We throw it off the ship to stop and pull it in to move.

Comment: F" posted this answer an hour before you

Comment: So? That's why we have spoilers for. Write what comes to your mind

Comment: The spoilers are there so that people don't have to see the solution before trying the puzzle themselves, not so that they don't have to see other answers before posting their own.

Comment: Did not see the solution

Comment: There are 4 more solutions at the same time I posted

Comment: Also if I had to do that I could have done for all other riddles puzzles as well

Answer (score 1):

It is an

> arrow

When you need me, you throw me away.

> You throw an arrow when you need it for hunting or shooting something.

But when you’re done with me, you bring me back.

> You get it back then for reusing it.

Answer (score 1):

It could be:

> A throwing toy for dogs (like a tennis ball)?

When you need me, you throw me away.

> You throw the toy/ball away for your dog to fetch.

But when you’re done with me, you bring me back.

> When you're done playing with your dog, you'll take the toy back home.

---

Alternative 1:

> Artificial fishing bait

When you need me, you throw me away.

> When you are fishing you cast your line with the fishing bait at the end of it.

But when you're done with me, you bring me back.

> When you are done fishing, you bring the fishing bait back again for next time

---

Alternative 2:

> Throwing knife (or any kind of throwing weapon)

When you need me, you throw me away.

> You throw the knife to attack - hence the name throwing knife ;)

But when you're done with me, you bring me back.

> When you are done (with the fight), you sheathe your knifes again.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this isn't the intended answer, but it could be

> yo-yo

because

> a yo-yo is thrown when one wants to *use* it, and is brought back when one is done playing with it.